# Do I point nginx proxy_pass to HTTP or HTTPS for node HTTPS server?

Tags: node.js, http, nginx, https, proxypass

I am using Nginx to point a subdomain to a different port that a node.js server is listening to.

It works fine for http, but now I need to switch over to https.

This is what I have right now in `sites-available/default`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name sub.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:2222;
    }
}
```

Now that I am switching my node server over to https do I need to change the `proxy_pass` to `https://example.com:2222`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [nginx proxy pass Node, SSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375659/nginx-proxy-pass-node-ssl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10375750/2525699) in my searches.

Turns out it's best to handle the SSL certification with nginx and leave node running a http server.

Answer (score 1):

> Now that I am switching my node server over to https do I need to change the proxy_pass to https://example.com:2222?

Short answer is no. It doesn't need to be same protocol for proxy as for incoming request
But you may require another directive

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```