# express modrewrite https and static files

Tags: node.js, mod-rewrite, express

I need an express redirect/rewrite to my backend( accepts https only on a specific port) and also to keep serving the static files(frontend) , but seems that I have something wrong ..

```
 var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');


app.use("/",express.static(__dirname + "/build"));

app.use(modRewrite([
  '^/auth/signin https://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/signin'
]));

var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Do you really need express for this? nginx is better in ssl termination, reverse proxy to node and serving static assets.

Comment: I'm open to use another thing instead of connect-modrewrite too

Comment: Heres the gist. 
1. use nginx to terminate ssl and as a reverse proxy to the node process.
2. use nginx to serve static files.

**Edit** - Add link for the above. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10375750/710005

Comment: Yeah I know ! , but this is for development so I run this file , in prod I have the nginx :) , but for development I don't want to install a local nginx too much config for new developers to config the project.

Comment: It's not that difficult, neither is it time consuming. I can write you a gist on how to setup. bonus points - set up vagrant/docker and share that with you team. Does not get any easier that this.

Comment: thank you @SwarajGiri , if no one else have a solution I will end up doing that ! :) , I had some trouble install nginx in mac (brew didn't install it correctly) , so I guess I can try vagrant! , not docker because I need a development environment with easy GUI access ,someones will prefer IDE rather than vim , thank you for your fast response !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change

```
app.use(modRewrite(['^/auth/signin https://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/signin']));
```

to

```
app.use(modRewrite(['^/auth/signin https://127.0.0.1:8444/auth/signin [P]']));
```

From the document:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-modrewrite#proxy-p

```
Proxy [P]
Proxy your requests

'^/test/proxy/(.*)$ http://nodejs.org/$1 [P]'
```

Comment: good catch ! @BlackMamba , after adding the P and adding process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0" , the https proxy works :)